# Syntax for an async arrow function

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, arrow-functions

I can mark a JavaScript function as "async" (i.e., returning a promise) with the `async` keyword. Like this:

```
async function foo() {
  // Do something
}
```

What is the equivalent syntax for arrow functions?

Comment: It's worth noting that at least firefox and babel does let you do that

Comment: `var foo = async () => await Promise.resolve('ha');` - works just fine

Comment: saying `it doesn't work` is meaningless ... are you getting an error? perhaps you're doing something else wrong, without the code that "doesn't work" and a meaningful description of how it doesn't work, can only guess that you're doing something wrong (or using an old browser)

Comment: @JaromandaX well I can't find it in any spec, so far at least

Comment: that may well be @Pointy, but it does work natively in current firefox and chrome and node.js (7.7.4)

Comment: The [ES2017 spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-async-arrow-function-definitions) has a section on async arrow function definitions @Pointy.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan yes I'm just getting to that; I figured it had to be somewhere because I saw some Babel discussions about it (thanks)

Comment: What do you mean by "*equivalent syntax for Node.js*"? As soon as node supports `async`/`await`, it will support exactly that syntax.

Comment: It turned my problem was actually that I hadn't updated node.js to the latest version.  I would have seen that immediately but I couldn't find a good example of correct syntax.  I've updated my question to reflect that.

Comment: @JaromandaX You're right.  I should have posted my error message.

Comment: @Bergi I edited in a hurry and made the silly mistake of writing "node.js" instead of "arrow functions"  See my updated question.

Comment: @BonsaiOak - you still can, it's not too late

Answer (score 1595, accepted):

Async **arrow functions** look like this:

```js
const foo = async () => {
  // do something
}
```

Async **arrow functions** look like this for a *single argument* passed to it:

```js
const foo = async evt => {
  // do something with evt
}
```

Async **arrow functions** look like this for *multiple arguments* passed to it:

```js
const foo = async (evt, callback) => {
  // do something with evt
  // return response with callback
}
```

The **anonymous** form works as well:

```js
const foo = async function() {
  // do something
}
```

An async function **declaration** looks like this:

```js
async function foo() {
  // do something
}
```

Using async function in a **callback**:

```js
const foo = event.onCall(async () => {
  // do something
})
```

Using [async method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await#asyncawait_class_methods) inside of a **class**:

```js
async foo() {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: The OP appears to be looking for a named, async, arrow function which is the one syntax you do not show.

Comment: Actually, `const foo = async () => {}` creates a named async function named `foo`. It's entirely possible to do named functions this way (just no hoisting). In ES2016+ assignment of an anonymous function to a variable names it after the variable if it is declared there.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum What changed in es2016+?  I thought it was always that way.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Please don't call it named function. In js, a named anonymous function is a very specific syntax `foo = function bar () {}` that was created to replace `arguments.callee` when writing recursive anonymous functions. What you have there is a variable named `foo` that is a reference to a function.

Comment: @slebetman since ES2015 when you do `const foo = async () => {}` the name of the function is set to `foo` - http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation and http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer-runtime-semantics-propertydefinitionevaluation - see discussion in https://esdiscuss.org/topic/name-anonymous-functions-on-property-assignments

Comment: What is the difference if we use async function with constanta. const somefunction = async () => {}

Comment: @FarisRayhan It's just as with other constants, the reference of the variable `somefunction` cannot be changed after it is set. (It points to your anonymous async function.)

Comment: If calling from another `async` function, you can also wait for anonymous/arrow functions using
  `await (async () => { // do something });`

Comment: I have defined my function like this:  getDataFromPhoneNumber = (phone) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{  /*stuff here*/ } } how do I make that async ?

Comment: @MLissCetrus just like the answer suggests: `async phone => {/* stuff here */}`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: `const foo = async () => …` sets the `.name` property on the function (just like `var foo = function () {…` did in ES5—this is only a change in that `const` an arrow functions did not exist in ES5— but that doesn't make the function a *named* function.  Consider: in the `var foo` case you can change the value of `foo` and whoops, function can no longer call itself.  That's different than `function foo() {…`, where `foo` can always call itself by that name.

Answer (score 153):

This the simplest way to assign an `async` arrow function **expression** to a **named** variable:

```
const foo = async () => {
  // do something
}
```

<sub>(Note that this is not strictly equivalent to `async function foo() { }`. Besides [the differences between the `function` keyword and an arrow expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/247696), the function in this answer is not ["hoisted to the top"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting).)</sub>

Comment: Note that a named function expression is a very specific syntax in javascript. This is NOT a named function expression. Using the right words is important to avoid confusion later on when one phrase can evolve to mean two things. FYI, a named function expression is: `foo = function myName () {}`. The name is `myName` and it is specified to only exist inside the anonymous function and not defined anywhere outside. It's purpose is to replace `arguments.callee` when writing recursive anonymous functions.

Comment: I was about to dispute you @slebetman on technicality, since this is a (arrow) function expression and you end up with a named function (ie `foo.name === 'foo'`). But only because it's in the initializer of a `const` *statement*—meaning it's not quite right to call this a "named async arrow function expression". You're also correct that a named function expression's name is only _bound_ inside its own body, but it is also stored in the function's `name` property, which is nice for debugging (and is more often the reason I'd name them).

Comment: To put it another way, there's no such thing as a "named arrow function expression", but it can become "named" by being part of a const or let _statement_ (not sure about var because of hoisting), in the sense of having a name `fn.name` as well as having a binding in scope (the variable).

Answer (score 106):

Immediately Invoked Async Arrow Function:

```
(async () => {
    console.log(await asyncFunction());
})();
```

Immediately Invoked Async Function Expression:

```
(async function () {
    console.log(await asyncFunction());
})();
```

Comment: That's the one i was looking for

Comment: [MDN Docs on async function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/async_function#using_async_function_expression) - scroll to page bottom

Answer (score 25):

```
async function foo() {
  // do something
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
const foo = async () => {
   // do something
}
```

Calling `foo` with one argument like in the following example:

```
async function foo(arg1) {
  // do something
}
```

Is equivalent to calling `foo` like this (both ways are acceptable since parentheses are optional but not required when just one argument is provided)

```
const foo = async arg1 => {
  // do something
}

const foo = async (arg1) => {
  // do something
}
```

if you call `foo` with two or more arguments

```
async function foo(arg1, arg2) {
  // do something
}
```

Is equivalent to: (parentheses are now required)

```
 const foo = async (arg1, arg2) => {
    // do something
 }
```

And for a practical example with an await use inside:

```
const foo = async () => await Promise.resolve('done');
```

Answer (score 22):

Async Arrow function syntax with parameters

```
const myFunction = async (a, b, c) => {
   // Code here
}
```

Answer (score 22):

**Basic Example**

```js
folder = async () => {
    let fold = await getFold();
    //await localStorage.save('folder');
    return fold;
  };
```

Answer (score 15):

You may also do:

```
 YourAsyncFunctionName = async (value) => {

    /* Code goes here */

}
```

Comment: with one param you don't need parenthesis.

YourAsyncFunctionName = async value => {

    /* Code goes here */

}

Comment: @TakácsZsolt it a matter of preference. What Justin did is not wrong. I like to put parenthesis just in case I have add more params in the future

Answer (score 7):

My async function

```
const getAllRedis = async (key) => {
  let obj = [];

  await client.hgetall(key, (err, object) => {
    console.log(object);
    _.map(object, (ob)=>{
      obj.push(JSON.parse(ob));
    })
    return obj;
    // res.send(obj);
});
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain how this code answers the question and improves on the many upvoted answers the question already has, so that it is useful to other users with similar issues. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 7):

```
const asynchronousFunction = async () => {
  // do something;
  // await something else;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For a static async arrow function, it works like this:

```
static myFunction = async () => {
    // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Most simplest way

```
   const MyFunction = async ()=>{
      // do something here
   }
```