# Defining functions with lambda expressions in Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, lambda

When defining an asynchronous function I normally go for

```
async function myFunc(){
 // ...
}
```

I would like to switch over to lambda expressions. I tried

```
async myFunc() => { // throws an syntax error
 // ...
}
```

and

```
myFunc = async () => { // weird things come up
 // ...
}
```

I think the second example does not work because this code would try to store the functions result into `myFunc` like

```
let myFunc = f(); // store the result
```

Is it possible to define functions with lambda expressions or are they only used within other functions?

Comment: [Check this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42964102/syntax-for-async-arrow-function)

Comment: oh, thanks, should we close this one?

Comment: I'll flag as duplicate or you can delete

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
const foo = async () => {
  // do something here
}
```