# Trying to define async function

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous

I'm trying to define an async function with an arrow function.  This code already throws an error, but I still want to know what the main error is.

```
async responseName = name => ('hello'+ name);  
responseName('joshua').then(response => console.log(response));
```

Comment: The syntax is wrong; the `async` keyword has to be part of the function definition.

Comment: It's not the *identifier* that's `async`, it's the *function*: `responseName = async name => ...`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax for async arrow function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42964102/syntax-for-async-arrow-function)

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error.  You cannot define an identifier as async:

```
const responseName = async (name) => `hello ${name}`;
```