# async arrow function SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, npm, async-await

I'm using node version 10.15.3, npm version 6.9.0, VS code, and firebase-functions version 2.2.0 on a windows pc. Adding async/await to my app.post() function causes this:

```
 Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Code in file 
 index.js can't be loaded.
 Is there a syntax error in your code?
 Detailed stack trace: /user_code/index.js:31
 app.post('/pay-now', async (req, res) => {
                       ^

 SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
     at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
     at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
     at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
     at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
     at getUserFunction (/var/tmp/worker/worker.js:439:24)
```

Here's my app.post():

```
app.post('/pay-now', async (req, res) => {
    // charge user's card
    const charge = await makeCharge(req, res)
    // store order info in database, returns address of order
    const address = await storeOrder(req, res, charge.id)
    // send email to customer
    await emailHandler.sendCustomerEmail(req, res)
    // send email to company letting them know they have a new order
    await emailHandler.sendLTEmail(req, res, address, true)
    return res.sendStatus(200)
})
```

I tried removing the async & await's in app.post(), but then I get the same error at the first use of async in the function makeCharge. Any idea on what could be wrong?

Comment: have you tried deleting the `node_modules` directory followed by `npm install`? Maybe you've changed node versions recently, and your modules were built with a different version?

Comment: What exactly did you do (run a command? do something in an editor?) to make that error appear?

Comment: @Robbie just tried that and got the same result

Comment: @DougStevenson i run `firebase deploy --only functions`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the default runtime for Cloud Funtions is node 6, which doesn't support async/await.  You will need to edit your package.json to [target the node 8 runtime](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_nodejs_version), which uses a version of JavaScript that does have async/await.

> Set the version by adding an engines field to the package.json file
>   that was created in your functions/ directory during initialization.
>   For example, if you prefer to use only version 8, edit package.json to
>   add this line:
>
> ```
> "engines": {"node": "8"}
> ```

If you have already deployed a version of the function, you will need to delete it and deploy again after this configuration is in place.

Comment: For me this is not the problem. I am on v14 of node.

Answer (score -1):

maybe you should take a look here : [Syntax for async arrow function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42964102/syntax-for-async-arrow-function)

There is no problem with your module, I think the arrow function is not well written.

**EDIT :**

I don't know much about arrow function, can you try to use a "normal function" something like :

```
  app.post('/pay-now', async function Myfunction (req, res) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work for me, the arrow creates a syntax error

Comment: `31:48  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "{"` on the line `app.post('/pay-now', async function (req, res) => {`

Comment: Hmm, don't know then, can you not use an arrow function? And try a "normal" function? Does this work?

Comment: the answer by @DougStevenson was able to fix the problem, thanks for the help though!