# Calling async function on javascript onclick (or any) events

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am trying es6 in js along with async/await.

What i have done is :

html code

```
  <input type="button" onclick="javascript:examplefunction()" />
```

Js code  in seperate example.js file, which is alreay included in html.

```
  const somefunction = (...args) => {
    let result =  feedReducer(args);
    // do something
  }
```

It works fine with this. But since i have to use **await** for some other function, inside examplefunction(), I did the normal arrow function to async as under

```
   const somefunction = async (...args) => {
    let result = await feedReducer(args);
    // do something
  }
```

Now i am getting

> Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

I am stuck here, what am i doing wrong ? I adopted the above syntax from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42964102/syntax-for-async-arrow-function). Any suggestion are appreciated. Thanks.

Actual Function:

```
    const preparationManager = async (...args) => {
        console.log(args.length);
        let feed_type = args[0], feed_id = args[1], feed_name = args[2], product_count = args[5];
        let index = args[7] | 0;
        jQuery("#loader").show();
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?option=com_cartproductfeed&task=tranquilizer.formatFeedsToParentChildJson',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType:'json',
            data: {feed_type: feed_type, feed_id:feed_id, feed_name: feed_name, index:index },
            success: function (res) {
                if(res.success === true){
                    if(res.do_repeat === true){
                        args.push(res.index);
                        preparationManager(args[0],args[1],args[2],args[3],args[4],args[5],args[6]);
                    }else{
                        console.log("feedreducer");
                        let result = await feedReducer(args, res);
                        console.log('result',result)
                        console.log("after result")
                    }
                    //window.location.href = base_url + 'index.php/etsy-listings';
                }else{
                    console.log(res);
                }
                jQuery("#loader").hide();
            }
        })
    };

    const feedReducer = async (...args) => {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?option=com_cartproductfeed&task=tranquilizer.formatFeedsToParentChildJson',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType:'json',
            data: {feed_type: feed_type, feed_id:feed_id, feed_name: feed_name, index:index },
            success: function (res) {
                if(res.success === true){
                    if(res.do_repeat === true){
                        args.push(res.index);
                       let reducerPromise = feedReducer(args[0],args[1],args[2],args[3],args[4],args[5],args[6]);
                       console.log(reducerPromise);
                    }else{
                        //TODO : handle completion of feedreducer
                    }
                    //window.location.href = base_url + 'index.php/etsy-listings';
                }else{
                    console.log(res);
                }
                jQuery("#loader").hide();
            }
        })
    };
```

Comment: The code you've shown wouldn't produce the mentioned error. Can you show the actual code which produces the problem? The examples above are confusing (function names don't all match, e.g. examplefunction vs. somefunction), and they don't reproduce the problem. We can't really help you if you don't show the code which is causing the issue.

Comment: P.S. Any reason you're still using archaic inline `onclick=` handlers within your HTML, instead of unobtrusive ones using `addEventListener` within the JS?

Comment: you can't await on a function which is not async and doesn't return a promise. check my answer.

Comment: @ADyson This project is old and I haven't changed the convention. Also I have added the actual code ion my query, please have a look at it, thanks.

Comment: Thanks to you all, I finally go the error and I solved it, It was due to the success function callback in ajax . We could solve it by using 
await jQuery.ajax({});

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hi Suz try the following code it is working for me.

```
function feedReducer(args){
    return new Promise((res,rej)=>{
    res(args);
  })
}

const somefunction = async (...args) => {
  let result = await feedReducer(args);
  console.log(result);
  // do something
}

somefunction('hello');
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

the above error you got suggests that your feedReducer is not an async function

Make sure the feedReducer returns a Promise. Good luck

Answer (score 21):

Use:

```js
document.getElementById("idButton").onclick=async() => {
  await promiseExample();
};
```

Comment: If the `promiseExample()` call is the only thing being done on the click event, would it matter if it was just called without the await like `onclick=promiseExample`?