# js define anonymous async function SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

```
async function (){
    // await somthing
}
```

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

but i can define normal function like

```
function (){
    // ...
}()
```

Comment: `but i can define normal function like` Nope. `Function statements require a function name`. Did you mean to use an IIFE?

Comment: Agreed, the second snippet throws a syntax error just as the first one does.

Comment: bunch of useful comments about the syntax differences in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42964102/syntax-for-async-arrow-function

Answer (score 2):

You need a function name for this syntax :

```
async function functionName(){
    // await somthing
}
```

You can use this syntax too if you don't want to name it :

```
async () => {
  //await something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

define an [anonymous] function and call immediately，parentheses needed

```
(async function (){
  return 1
}) () // and call it , Promise {<resolved>: 1}
```