# What does ()=>async()=>{} mean?

Tags: ecmascript-6, redux, redux-thunk

I'm confused with that redux thunk action:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const GET_CHANNELS = 'GET_CHANNELS'

export const getChannels = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const res = await axios.get('https://v-forum-api.bahdcasts.com/api/channels')
    dispatch({
        type: GET_CHANNELS,
        payload: res.data
    })
}
```

What does the following construct mean?

```
const getChannels=()=>async()=>{}
```

Can you please provide any article link for that expression? 
Thank you

Comment: It's a function that returns a function (async in this case). Read the redux-thunk documentation.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42964310/1871033 - https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Syntax for async arrow function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42964102/syntax-for-async-arrow-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a function that returns another (async) function.

Ignoring the differences in semantics of `this` between arrow functions and regular functions, a possibly clearer way to write the same thing with regular functions would be:

```js
const getChannels = function () {
  return async function (dispatch, getState) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

The caller would call `getChannels()` and get a function back, which could then be called as well.

```js
const innerFunction = getChannels()
await innerFunction(dispatch, getState)
```

Comment: i noted you answer you are great

Answer (score 0):

`const getChannels = () => async() => {}`

is somehow equal to:

```
function getChannels() {
  return async function() {

  }
}
```

using arrow functions (which changes the usage of `this`) & getChannels is constant block-leveled variable.