# How to run async function outside ngZone?

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, async-await, zone.js

I have tried to tun script outside current Zone:

```
  async ngAfterViewInit(): Promise<void> {
     this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
       await this.run();
     });
  }
  
  async run() { // TODO }
```

I get this error:

```
'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules.ts
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Syntax for an async arrow function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42964102/syntax-for-an-async-arrow-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ngAfterViewInit function is asynchronous but then you've used this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular with a non asynchronous callback function.

You're code needs to look like this...

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(async () => {
        await this.run();
    });
}

async run() { // TODO }
```