# How can i check a JWT token is valid using an async function route with nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express

I am following the guide below to verify that only registered users can send requests to my backend nodejs server, my frontend is sending requests with an authorization header that contains a token and that part is working well. The nodejs backend should then check the token is valid before sending a response:
https://www.tonyvu.co/posts/jwt-authentication-node-js

The example shows i should add 'AuthenticateJWT' like the following to my route:

```
app.post(“/api/token”, authenticateJWT, (req, res) => {
...
});
```

However my route is an async function and i can't find the correct syntax to add it. My code is the following:

```
router.post('/account/user_load_balance',  async function (req, res) {

 ...  
});
```

I have tried the following:

```
router.post('/account/user_load_balance',  async function, authenticateJWT (req, res)     try {
 ...
});
```

but this gives me an error:

```
Unexpected token ','
```

what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn the example code:

```
app.post(“/api/token”, authenticateJWT, (req, res) => {
    ...
});
```

into an async function example, simply by adding the `async` keyword to the function that already exists:

```
app.post(“/api/token”, authenticateJWT, async (req, res) => {
    ...
});
```

It should be trivial to adapt this to your own use, assuming that you have an `authenticateJWT` that's already functional.

See also:

- [Syntax for an async arrow function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42964102/syntax-for-an-async-arrow-function)