# Correct typescript async await syntax with typed arrow functions

Tags: javascript, typescript

Similar question for vanilla JS [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42964102/syntax-for-an-async-arrow-function). I however want to use async await with typescript function as below.

Javascript

```
const foo = async () => {
  // do something
}
```

Initial attempt

```
export const fetchAirports = async (): Airport[] => {
  //More code
  return airports;
};
```

but i get an error **ts(1055) Type 'Airport[]' is not a valid async function return type in ES5/ES3 because it does not refer to a Promise-compatible constructor value.** which to me sounds like a lot of jargon. Please remember **I have to specify a return type in the function declaration** otherwise it nullifies the need for typescript in the first place.

Comment: JavaScript async function will always return a `Promise`. Try changing the return type `Airport[]` you specified to `Promise<Airport[]>`

Comment: It's not a syntax problem, it's a type problem. An async function **cannot** return something that's not a promise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```js
export const fetchAirports = async (): Promise<Airport[]> => {
    //More code
    return airports;
}
```

Or

```js
export const fetchAirports = async (): Promise<Array<Airport>> => {
    //More code
    return airports;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use `async` function, it wraps return value in `Promise`, so instead `Airport[]` you should wrap it in Promise like this: `Promise<Airport[]>`